# Leaflet- Doing something on-click in certain regions of the map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want there to be a reaction to when a leaflet map is clicked on, and an 'alert' to happen. But the thing is, I only want that reaction to happen if the click was **outside** of some polygon shapes I have on the map. I've tried:

```
function onMapClick(e) {
     alert("Nothing to do here") ;
 }
 mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

It works fine if I don't click on one of my polygons. But, if I click on a polygon, I'll get their actions, plus still get this alert, which I don't want to happen. This is a possibility I can't find anybody mention anywhere, so I feel like I've run out of leads. Where should I look to learn how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Leaflet 1.0.x, interactive events on some map layers (such as `L.Polygon`s) bubble up to the map by default. See [bug #3307](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/3307) for details and background.

The documentation doesn't mention this explicitly, but hopefully will get better with [PR #4883](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/4883/files). Just call `L.DomEvent.stopPropagation()` as needed, inside the polygon event handler.

Comment: I tried calling that inside the polygons' layer click handling function and the map alert stopped showing when I click on a polygon shape. But the thing is, the actions I have in that function (for polygon clicks) also stopped happening, which is an undesired side effect!

Comment: You're probably doing things in the wrong order. See https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/zuh/edit?html,console,output for inspiration.

Comment: I've got the hang of it now! I really appreciate the help in this comment

Answer (score 0):

You can try this trick, Insert a click event on Polygon:

```
var onClick = function(event){
//Do nothing
};
var poly = new L.Polygon([
        [79.07181, -100.63477], 
        [79.06348, -90.43945], 
        [77.52312, -90.52734], 
        [77.50412, -94.21875], 
        [77.41825, -94.35059], 
  ]);
poly.on('click', onClick);
```